# changing css background-color property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the property of background color on `mouseover` of the `nav ul li` element but when I select another element of the same kind I want the first one to revert its color and the newly selected to change color and so on.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('nav ul li').on('mouseover', function() {
        if ($(this).css('background-color') == '#BBB') {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#36D900"); 
        } else {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#BBB");
        }   
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay, you have this code. What is your problem?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Use class instead of use css background color in jquery. The color is different dependent on browsers

Comment: Use hover event in jqyery

Comment: sry, aded an explanation now hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code

```
$('nav ul li').hover(function(){
   $('nav ul li').css("background-color", "#BBB");
   $(this).css("background-color", "#36D900"); 
});
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. I don't know why mine doesn't work but this seems to do the job. Jquery seems to be a mess but I guess JS is a bigger mess :).